# Webscraping javascript dynamic website using Requests and Bs4 (not Selenium)

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to make an automatic file downloader, but for that, I have to scrape the website "downloads" section, which is located after a login validation.

The problem is that this "downloads" page is dynamically generated and I'm having trouble with what tools to use for that because using Selenium just isn't practical, as I wanted to avoid precisely the whole starting a browser and login process.

I used Requests to open a session and insert my payload in the login area. I was trying to implement `requests_html` after the login was successful, so it could render the HTML without using Scrapy, Splash or Docker, as these modules are a bit too advanced for me right now.

The Requests session started conflicting with the requests_html module, so I commented it on my code to disable it. Before I implemented the requests_html module I was not getting any errors and managed to print out the page HTML, but without rendering the javascript. Here's what it looks like:

```
# importing the modules we are going to need for scraping

import requests
import pyppdf.patch_pyppeteer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests_html import HTMLSession

# importing the username and password from the .env file (in the same folder)
# using the dotenv module

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

user = os.environ.get("USER")
password = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")

# for the login, we need to create a dictionary that contains the necessary input information
# (username and password that was imported from the .env file)
# with the "name" values defined in the HTML file of the site

payload = {
    "usr": "user", # "usr" = name, followed by the input value
    "passwd": "password" # "passwd" = name, followed by the input value

}

# defining the URL we want to scrape and the pre-login page as well
# (these are not the real URLs)

login_url = "https://www.example_site.com/"
real_url = "https://www.example_site.com/modules/user/DownloadsCentral"

# defining functions to start and close sessions

def open_session():

    # defining a function attribute to manually close the session afterward
    
    open_session.session = requests.Session()
    open_session.session.post(login_url, data = payload) # send (post) data (payload) to the site
    open_session.session.get(real_url) # requesting a session start in the url we want to scrape

    # HTML part (haven't figured out what went wrong, so I switched back to open a session with Requests)

    # html_session = HTMLSession()
    # html_session.post(login_url, data = payload)
    # open_session.get_session = html_session.get(real_url)

# close the session (required) by calling the function close_session() below

def close_session():
    requests.Session.close(open_session.session)



# calling the function to open a session

open_session()

# HTML render (didn't work)

# js_url = open_session.real_session.html.render(sleep = 2, keep_page = True, scrolldown = 0)
# files = js_url.html.find("css searcher")
# print(files)

# once we're able to establish a connection with the internal URL
# we can parse the HTML file using the lxml parser module

soup = bs(real_url.html, "lxml") # soup (html) = bs4 function of the html we're using parsed by lxml
print(soup.prettify())


# closing the session after everything is done

close_session()
```

(I'm new to posting questions here so if I posted some unnecessary info, my bad.)

[image of the data I'm trying to scrape is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHvyU.png)

Comment: What's the actual login URL? Every webpage/service is different, it's basically impossible to say without the URL. Unless it's a paid service, I would be willing to make a dummy account just to see what's on the other side of the login page.

Comment: Well, it's actually my school's website hahah, so unless you were a student or a teacher there you couldn't really log in, that's why I didn't include it. But I can include the original pre-login page, although I don't really need  help in that area, I'm not sure if it would help you out that much either

Comment: I see. Yeah, the pre-login page wouldn't help me. Let me see if I've got this correct: Using your script, you were able to access the "downloads" page after logging in, but you are not able to scrape the contents of the "downloads" page because the contents of the page are populated asynchronously using JavaScript, yes? Depending on what the content is, it's possible that the page is making requests to an API serving JSON, in which case you can simply imitate such a request to get the content you want. Do you know how to log your network traffic in your browser?

Comment: Using the inspect menu right? I have tried it and didn't really understand that much because I'm just starting out with programming and have almost no experience with Java, but as far as I could see it was a JSON request in the Query String Parameters and the Response Headers (not sure if it's what you meant), it was something else in the Request Headers page

Comment: I toggled to only show XHR traffic, hiding all URLs data and disabling the cache, this gave me four requests, and one of them is the one containing the data I'm looking for in a list format. And answering your other question, the files I want to download are mainly Word, Pdf, and PowerPoint, and yes, it loads asynchronously, so I can't scrape it directly.

Comment: Yes, XHR traffic is what I was referring to. Can you post the request URL of the resource containing the data you're looking for? Or does the query string contain or the request header contain sensitive information? Also, when you say the data is in a "list format", do you mean JSON? Also, what does the data look like? Are they URLs to the actual resources you want to download (PDF, etc.) in a list?

Comment: I will post what the data looks like, but I'm not sure what I can show or not in the headers tab (as I said I don't have a lot of experience with networking and Java), so I prefer not to share that info before researching more about it, but the content type in Response Headers is applications/JSON, and in the Query String it's also JSON. The request method is GET. I didn't see a link to directly download the files. Also, the data is in Portuguese, not in English, so extra challenge there hahah.

Comment: Thanks for adding the image! Too bad there isn't a URL for each resource in the JSON. When you started logging your XHR traffic, did you refresh the page first, or did you start logging when parts of the page were already loaded? It's possible that your browser made another initial API request before you started logging traffic, so I would clear the log, start recording XHR traffic and then refresh the page so that you can be sure you are capturing all traffic. I'm hoping that maybe you'll get another JSON containing URLs.

Comment: I tried doing that and it's the same, no link or URL. In the HTML elements, there are no links as well.

Comment: If you want to be super hardcore, you could set breakpoints in the relevant parts of the HTML to trigger the debugger when the DOM changes, and then try to figure out where the JavaScript script is getting the URLs from. Sorry, I can't really think of anything else.

Comment: I'll research more into that, thanks for the suggestion! If you think of something else let me know